# Trying to replicate a Python list in Swift

Tags: python, swift, swift2

In Python, I'm able to do this:

```
day0 = 0
day1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
        11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
        21, 22, 23, 24, 25]

day2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
        11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
        21, 22, 23, 24, 25]

day3 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
        11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
        21, 22, 23, 24, 25]

day4 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
        11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
        21, 22, 23, 24, 25]

month0 = 0
january = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4] 
february = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4] 
march = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4] 
april = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4] 
may = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]
june = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4] 
july = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4] 
august = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4] 
september = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]
october = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4] 
november = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]
december = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]

calendar = [month0, january, february, march, april, may, june, july,       august, september,
            october, november, december]
```

then this:

```
print calendar[2][3[0][3]]
```

and I would get the number 3 returned back to me. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this in Swift.

I can create the lists in basically the same way in Swift

```
var day0 = 0
var day1 = [0, 8, 2, 3, 4]
var day2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
var day3 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
var day4 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

var month0 = 0
var january = [[day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]]
var february = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]
var march = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]
var april = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]
var may = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]
var june = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]
var july = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]
var august = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]
var september = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]
var october = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]
var november = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]
var december = [day0, day1, day2, day3, day4]

var calendar = [month0, january, february, march, april, may, june, july, august, september, october, december]
```

But when I try to call an element, I get an error

```
 BedTimeLabel.text = String(january[1],][1])
 *** Expected expression in list of expressions ***
```

Or when I try it this way

```
BedTimeLabel.text = String(format: january[1],arguments: [1])
```

I get this error

```
Cannot convert value of type 'NSArray' to expected argument type 'String'
```

Comment: you have syntax error in Python and Swift. Why do you use `[[` instead of `[` in Swift `january = [[ ...]]` ?

Comment: Probably a typo. What do you want to do with `var day0 = 0` and `var month0 = 0` though? Because of this, the array needs to be a `NSArray` instead of a "simple" `[[[Int]]]`.

Comment: @furas That's part of my frustration. I read on another forum that that was the syntax

Comment: You get error, cause you passing integer array to String format which should be a String. What output string should produce your misterios String(...) operation?

Comment: Also, instead of String(...) you can just use string interpolation, like `BedTimeLabel.text = "\(november[2][1])"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no knowledge about Python so I'm not entirely sure I understand your question.

From what I understood you have a multi dimensional array which just looks like this in Swift:

```
let day1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
let day2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
let day3 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
let day4 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

let jan = [day1, day2, day3, day4]
let feb = [day1, day2, day3, day4]
let mar = [day1, day2, day3, day4]
let apr = [day1, day2, day3, day4]

let calendar = [jan, feb, mar, apr]

let result = calendar[2][3][3]        // 3
```

Comment: I have pretty much no knowledge of swift.

Comment: The only thing I'm not sure about is, what does he wants to do with the `var month0 = 0` and `var day0 = 0`?

Comment: Honestly in python your not supposed to do var or int or such so that's a syntax error.

Comment: day0 = 0 though is just a int that =s 0

Comment: Well, if that isn't needed (in Swift) then he can just omit it and the answer is pretty simple :).

Comment: Yea, it is pretty simple then "Look's up what omit means"

Comment: I tried what you said, but I got an error 'Type NSObject has no subscript members'

Comment: Did you keep the `var month0 = 0` and `var day0 = 0`?

Comment: the reason why i used zeros in the first place was so that the user could simply type a number that corresponded to the numeric month or day, since the 1st element is a 0. guess I'll have to figure a way around that.

Comment: Yea, I already thought so. You can do the same but instead of an `Int`, it should be a `[Int]` i.e.: `var day0 = [0]` and `var month0 = [day0]`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: On a sidenote, I think using a multidimensional array like this isn't too safe. Instead you should use a dictionary, check if the data exists and then return it.

Comment: @Eendje For some reason i'm now getting an error "ambiguous use of subscript" for let result = calendar[1][1][1]